# JVM running old-gen garbage collection when old gen is 'empty'

Tags: java, clojure, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a Clojure app running that has a lot of memory churn for large heap allocations, so it has appropriately set JVM opts:

```
-Xmx13g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=10G -server -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

This works most of the time and avoids problems where the new gen overflows into old gen (sometimes still makes it to survivor generation, but not always), but sometimes we see situations like the one pictured where the JVM runs CMS/old gen garbage collection really hard when the new generation is full. It's my understanding, though, that this should be handled by the new generation garbage collector.

[image]

Two questions. Why is the old gen garbage collector running when old gen is nearly empty but new gen has stuff? And is there any further tuning I can do that would reduce the GC pauses/slowdowns this inevitably causes?

ETA: Running on OpenJDK 8.

ETA 2: GC logs: https://gist.github.com/gworley3/6abb9ab52320c6cbd508

Comment: I see no indication that oldspace is garbagecollecting.

Comment: based on seeing that a large chunk of CPU time is given to running CMS (see Garbage collection CPU time chart in image)

Comment: you should enable GC logging and post a reasonably large sample of them. you should also specify which JVM version you're using. Also, your new gen size seems excessive.

Comment: sorry, i meant to include that info: OpenJDK 8. also, new gen size needs to be that big because code ends up allocating 7 to 8 GB of ram for data structures for occasional short-lived requests.

Comment: you still haven't included GC logs.

Comment: i'm still trying to produce some for an event like this. i can't seem to get the scenario to replicate very easily but it has happened repeatedly on production every few days so hopefully i will catch the logs from the next event and can post here.

Comment: managed to capture some GC logs from an event like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer:

CMS is spending too much time scanning the nearly 10GB Young Gen when it doesn't have. You can prevent the CMS collector from needlessly running by adding the options:

`‑XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly ‑XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=<K>`

Where *K* is an arbitrary fraction of Occupied Old Gen space.

## Long Answer:

Referring to the [Oracle CMS Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html):

> The CMS collector pauses an application twice during a concurrent collection cycle. The first pause is to mark as live the objects directly reachable from the roots (for example, object references from application thread stacks and registers, static objects and so on) and from elsewhere in the heap (for example, the **young generation**). This first pause is referred to as the initial mark pause. The second pause comes at the end of the concurrent tracing phase and finds objects that were missed by the concurrent tracing due to updates by the application threads of references in an object after the CMS collector had finished tracing that object. This second pause is referred to as the remark pause.

CMS is making two *stop-the-world* pauses, each time scanning the Young Gen for marking. Looking at the first three lines of your log, you can see that the initial mark takes 5 seconds before a ParNew, and .25 seconds after. The remark sees a similair decrease in time.

```
<190>1 2015-12-18T08:44:54.194216+00:00 host app web.1 - [GC[YG occupancy: 489826 K (9437184 K)][Rescan (parallel) , 0.2520950 secs][weak refs processing, 0.0000180 secs][scrub string table, 0.0008190 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 64504K(107240K)] 554330K(9544424K), 0.2530410 secs] [Times: user=1.95 sys=0.02, real=0.25 secs]

<190>1 2015-12-18T08:44:49.937257+00:00 host app web.1 - [GC[ParNew:   8418004K->93508K(9437184K), 0.0488580 secs] 8482343K->158013K(9544424K), 0.0489980 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]

<190>1 2015-12-18T08:44:48.651086+00:00 host app web.1 - [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 64339K(107240K)] 7800216K(9544424K), 5.0756660 secs] [Times: user=5.08 sys=0.00, real=5.08 secs]
```

Your Old Gen space is hardly reduced after each CMS cycle, so the overhead is certainly not worth it. Reducing the frequency of CMS cycles would be one possible solution.

Comment: this seems to have solved the problem. setting the occupancy fraction to 70 worked well. thanks for your insights into how cms works: i was under the impression that like with the serial gc it would only run if there was stuff in old gen.